# Network Indicator icon in system tray is missing in 12.04

Tags: network-manager, icons, indicator

My Network indicator icon is missing in 12.04.

I have tried all answers of askubuntu but no luck.

When I run `nm-applet` or `nm-applet &` in terminal it gives message as

```
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

I have tried conf-editor also but nm-applet is not appearing under org category.

I dont know what to do, Please help me.

Comment: Check `Network` in `system settings`.